# How is merging working in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge

Imagine I've a difference in a piece of code between the branch A and the branch B which is seen by SVN as a conflict.

When I try to merge the possible situations are:

1. only A has been modified
2. only B has been modified
3. Both A and B have been modified

Is SVN providing me this information? Since I'm getting crazy trying to compare some huge CSS files...

Comment: Conflict means "Both A and B have been modified". Otherwise, it isn't a conflict at all.

Comment: I suggest reading the whole chapter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html ask about the particular part which you don't understand then.

Comment: and this one: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, conflict means that *both* branches have modified the same code. Otherwise, there wouldn't be a conflict and Subversion would have been able to merge changes automatically.

Whenever there's a conflict related to file contents (directories are a different story) Subversion provides the following hints:

1. All three involved files are dumped into your working copy:

   - `foo.php.merge-left.r832`
   - `foo.php.merge-right.r833`
   - `foo.php.working`
2. Original file `foo` gets conflicts markers:

   ```
   <<<<<<< .working
    * Lower bound for DATETIME columns at SQL Server 2005
    */
   define('MIN_YEAR_SQL_SERVER', 1753);

   /*
    * Lower bound for date controls regarding building date
   =======
    * Lower bound for date controls
   >>>>>>> .merge-right.r833
   ```

   ... where first block is your current code and second block is incoming code.

Third-party merge tools can make this easier (or harder) but this is the information Subversion provides.

Comment: Do you know any 3rd parties tools?

Comment: None I'd particularly recommend. I use TortoiseMerge (Windows-ony) but I'm not a great fan.

Comment: Do a web search for "3-way file diff" and you'll get a few results. That "3-way" feature is key: it allows you to see for each line exactly what changed due to each version, rather than just seeing that the lines differ. Often the diff tool can even make most of the changes for you without intervention. Personally I use KDiff3, but there are plenty other tools out there, paid or free; and stackoverflow explicitly holds software recommendations as off-topic.